# Pandas Dataframe. Add multiple columns based on nonnull values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe example.

```
np.random.seed(66)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(5, 3), 
    columns=list('ABC'), 
    index=['R{}'.format(i) for i in range(5)]
)
df[df < .5] = None
df.head()

    A    B    C
R0  NaN  NaN  NaN
R1  0.67 NaN  NaN
R2  0.75 0.55 0.51
R3  NaN  NaN  0.82
R4  NaN  NaN  0.67
```

Solution for one column

```
df['A_percent'] = (df.loc[df['A'].notnull(),['A']] * 100).astype(np.int32)
df.head()

   A    B    C    A_percent
R0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
R1 0.67 NaN  NaN  67.0
R2 0.75 0.55 0.51 75.0
R3 NaN  NaN  0.82 NaN
R4 NaN  NaN  0.67 NaN
```

Everything breaks when I try the same for multiple columns

```
df['A_percent', 'B_percent'] = (df.loc[df['A', 'B'].notnull(),['A', 'B']] * 100).astype(np.int32)
```

Can it be done at all in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html), then boolean mask should be removed:

```
df[['A_percent', 'B_percent']] = np.floor(df[['A', 'B']] * 100)
print (df)
           A         B         C  A_percent  B_percent
R0       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
R1  0.679109       NaN       NaN       67.0        NaN
R2  0.758416  0.557619  0.514803       75.0       55.0
R3       NaN       NaN  0.829095        NaN        NaN
R4       NaN       NaN  0.678006        NaN        NaN
```

Your solution should be changed by replace missing values to some numeric, e.g. `0`, so possible converting to `integer` and for new column use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
mask = df[['A','B']].notnull()
df1 = (df[['A','B']].fillna(0)*100).astype(np.int32)

df[['A_percent', 'B_percent']] = df1.where(mask)
print (df)
           A         B         C  A_percent  B_percent
R0       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
R1  0.679109       NaN       NaN       67.0        NaN
R2  0.758416  0.557619  0.514803       75.0       55.0
R3       NaN       NaN  0.829095        NaN        NaN
R4       NaN       NaN  0.678006        NaN        NaN
```